# MailChimp API 1.3 + Hominid 3 + Groupings

Tags: ruby, mailchimp

For some reason I just can't get the latest version of Hominid working with groupings in MailChimp.

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing:

```
info[:GROUPINGS] = { 'name' => 'Locations', 'groups' => 'SomeLocation' }    
mailchimp = Hominid::API.new(MAILCHIMP_API_KEY)
list_id = mailchimp.find_list_id_by_name MAILCHIMP_LIST_NAME
mailchimp.list_update_member(list_id, email_value, info)
```

I've tried seemingly every combination of arrays and hashes to get the groupings working, but I keep getting variations of this error:

```
<270> "V" is not a valid Interest Grouping id for the list: Test List
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that it needs an array of hashes:

```
info[:GROUPINGS] = [ { 'name' => 'Locations', 'groups' => 'SomeLocation' } ]
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: For anyone doing this with PHP, you'll have something like: array(array('name' => "Locations", 'groups' => "SomeLocation,OtherLocation")).  Took me a while to figure out the right combination... Argh!

Comment: Thanks @Omega - that was baffling me completely! The MailChimp API really needs some concrete samples